# Javascript regex: matching a span element with a certain class, from beginning to end

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a `span` element with a certain class name and everything that comes between its start and finish.

My regex is `/<\/?(span)[^>]*"myClass".*?<\/span>/gi`. It works on `<span class="myClass">...</span>`, but it fails on something like below, only extending to the first `</span>`:

```
<span class="myClass"> ... <span class="anything else"> ... </span> ... </span>
```

How can I match it all from beginning to end?

Comment: [relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 2):

This regex should do the job for you:

`/span\s(?:class="myClass")>(.*)<\/span\>/`

```
var txt = '<span class="myClass"><span class="anything else"></span></span>';
txt.match(/span\s(?:class="myClass")>(.*)<\/span\>/)
```

**Output**

`["span class="myClass"><span class="anything else"></span></span>", "<span class="anything else"></span>"]`

```
var txt = '<span class="myClass">foobar</span>';
txt.match(/span\s(?:class="myClass")>(.*)<\/span\>/)
```

**Output**

`["span class="myClass">foobar</span>", "foobar"]`

Comment: Well, it simply extends to the last `</span>`, which may be outside of the desired `<span class="myClass">`. For example, it matchs all of the following `<span class="myClass">foobar</span><span></span>`.

Comment: You need to have a very good and serious reason to use regexp instead of the DOM api to get a html element. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Robert I don't disagree at all, just trying to answer the question that was posed.

Answer (score 1):

It is bad practice to use regexp for parsing html. You can work with DOM instead. This should do that you want:

```
var value = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need `REGEX` only `Jquery` `Find`
suppose that we will ad a div

```
<div id="myid"><span class="myClass"> ... <span class="anything else"> ... </span> ... </span></div>

spanList = $('myid').find('.myClass, .anything else');
```